# Stop browser tabs from running when in background

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to contain an executable (google chrome) and prevent it from running when it is not the active window. This means when it is in the background it should not be running arbitrary scripts, sending/receiving network calls, etc.

Preferably this would extend to each tab in Chrome, so only the active tab would be running.

It is my understanding that some addons such as 'no-script' and 'umatrix' can assist here, but it requires a lot of tweaking for each individual website, and does not block everything when the tab is in the background. These addons do not seem to be the solution to my issue.

Comment: You can try out extensions like The Great Suspender etc.

Comment: This looks pretty good. I'll try it out. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What about disabling chrome altogether if it's in the background?